# OleDB Select Where not Exists

Tags: c#, select, oledb

I want to `SELECT` all `JobTitles` that aren't used in the `Employees` table, so they do exist in the `JobTitle` table but are not associated with any `Employees` in that table. This is what I have tried so far;

```
private static void NullJobTitle()
{
    using (OleDbConnection dbfCon = new OleDbConnection(dbfConstr))
    {
        dbfCon.Open();
        var dbfCmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT j.jbt_title
        FROM jobtitle j
        LEFT JOIN employs e ON j.jbt_title = e.em_title
        WHERE j.jbt_title IS NULL", dbfCon);

        var dTable = new DataTable();
        var dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(dbfCmd);
        dataAdapter.Fill(dTable);
        WriteToCSV(dTable, "presets");
    }
}
```

However it is not working so far, nothing is written to my `CSV` file but no errors are thrown either. How can I modify this to work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your query string is wrong. If you want to get unused title from table jobtitle it should be like this:

```
SELECT j.jbt_title
FROM jobtitle j
LEFT JOIN employs e ON j.jbt_title = e.em_title
WHERE e.em_title IS NULL
```